# How to generate inner java classes with json schema?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

Is it possible to generate inner java classes using json schema? 
The plugin I am using for generating my pojos is jsonschema2pojo(http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

If yes, how?

Currently I couldn't find any information/examples regarding this on web, neither on http://json-schema.org/ or on http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: What are inner classes?

Comment: @tomredfern  Nested classes. Hope I am not wrong and this notion is interchangeable. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Comment: JSON Schema doesn't have a concept of classes, let alone inner classes.  Are you talking about generating classes from schemas?  Schemas can be nested to any level, but how that gets generated into classes depends on the specific code generation tool you are using.

Comment: @Jason I will add details about this. I am using jsonschema2pojo plugin. See updates

Comment: @tomredfern any other details can help you?

Comment: @Jason any other details can help you?

Comment: Whoever voted this as negative/close at least can bring it on if he has any other unclarity why this question is not a good/constructive one and brings no value. I'm trying to eliminate confusion/ambiguity if any

Comment: @Flowryn I haven't used jsonschema2pojo, so I'm unable to help any further.  Good luck.

Comment: Found any solution?

Comment: None until now. However we changed our approach at that time and we didn't generate inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

No. I have experimented with this trying to achieve the same and have concluded that jsonschema2Pojo doesn't support it.

Neither

```json
{
...
   "foo": {
      "$ref" : "#/definitions/Bar.Foo"
   }
...
"definitions" : {
   "Bar.Foo": {
      "type": object,
      ...
   }
}
```

or

```json
{
...
   "foo": {
      "$ref" : "#/definitions/Foo"
   }
...
"definitions" : {
   "Foo": {
      "type": object,
      "javaType": "org.example.Bar.Foo"
      ...
   }
}
```

works.

I'd recommend posting this issue to their jira, last time I checked they were quite responsive.

You might also want to consider other limitations of jsonschema2Pojo and think about whether the tool makes sense at all.

On the project I have been working on it is becoming more more clear that we might have been better off not using the tool at all, because people have been inventing all kinds of exotic workarounds to compensate for shortcomings of the tool (like being able to specify a base class for a generated class.